# How to prevent code in Android Service run Twice

Tags: android, service, background

I'm trying to create a Service to checking data and push notification. I have a problem with call service again after stop it. It like 2 instance or more of the service is running(// my code here running twice and call notification twice after stop and start, I comment it cuz it is a long code xD). How can I prevent it?

From some answer i found, i try to put my thread in onCreate() but no effect.

Here is my code:

```
public class CheckDataAndPushNotificationService extends Service {
public CheckDataAndPushNotificationService() {
}


private String token;
ArrayList<UsefulRequestData> oldData;
ArrayList<UsefulRequestData> newData;
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;
ApiUtil apiUtil;
String notificationNewRequest = "Có yêu cầu mới.";
String notificationCancelRequest = "Có yêu cầu đã bị hủy.";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    newData = new ArrayList<>();
    localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    apiUtil = new ApiUtil(this);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        // my code here
    }, 0, 5000);
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void createNotification(String message) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("RequestNotification", "RequestNotification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("Use to notify if you have new or cancel request.");
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "RequestNotification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_app_icon) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle("XCaller") // title for notification
            .setContentText(message)// message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)// clear notification after click
            .setSound(defaultSound);


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IntentService`. It is perfect for your needs. It automatically creates separated thread for the work that you send to it.

From [Documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService)

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through Context.startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as
>   needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops
>   itself when it runs out of work.
>
> This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks
>   from an application's main thread. The IntentService class exists to
>   simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics. To use it,
>   extend IntentService and implement
>   onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent). IntentService will receive the
>   Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate.
>
> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by override method onDestroy() and cancel the timer. When you call stopService(), onDestroy() will run.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```